# How to add multiple colours in Googleway:add_polyline function in R?

Tags: r, colors, polyline, googleway

I want to add different colours for each line in polyline function.

Here is the code that I have tried:

```
google_map(key = map_key, style = style) %>%
  add_polylines(data = poly_df, polyline = encode_pl(lat = poly_df$lat, lon = poly_df$long),stroke_weight = 1.2, stroke_opacity = 0.1, stroke_colour = "#CCCFFF")
```

I have also tried `stroke_colour= "colour"` but this shows some error.

Comment: I don't think you're using `add_polylines()` correctly. If you data is a data.frame of lon and lat columns, you should use `add_polylines( data = poly_df, lon = "long", lat = "lat")`

Comment: But to properly help you I would need to have an example of your `poly_df`. The help file for `?add_polylines` contains a few examples.